# I have created a custom workfow on a form library in a subsite now I want to deploy this workflow to all 200 subsites how can I achive it?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

In reusable workflow I don't get current item fields which are required in the workflow.

Comment: Please add more information to this post, we need as much information as possible to be able to help you

Comment: I'm going to assume your current situation is this:

You have created a custom workflow on a List with no content type and you want to deploy it on other lists.

If this is the case I'm gonna have to dissappoint you and tell you that you will have to make a content type available and then you can create a *Reusable* workflow connected to this content type and then this will allow you to deploy and associate it to other lists, given that they have this content type

Comment: I have created workflow on form library say for eg. http://server/jobs/job1/library now I want this workflow to be deployed to http://server/jobs/job2/library, http://server/jobs/job3/library, http://server/jobs/job4/library,